# Salsa20 / ChaCha with 128 bit keys

Tags: chacha, salsa20

According to wikipedia both Salsa20 and ChaCha support both 128 and 256-bit keys.

The initial state for each has 8 words of key, where each word is 32 bits. 32*8 = 256. My question is...  how is one supposed to expand a 128-bit key to fill in the 256-bits needed for the initial state?

The most obvious way would be to just append the 128-bit key to itself but in some ciphers, like RC2 or RC4 or Blowfish or the key goes through a key expansion step to expand the key to whatever size is ultimately needed - a key expansion step that doesn't simply append the orig key to itself.

Comment: Page 8 of [the spec](https://cr.yp.to/snuffle/spec.pdf).  If you're this curious about Salsa20 and ChaCha don't mess around with Wikipedia, just go straight to DJB's pages on [Salsa](https://cr.yp.to/snuffle.html) and [ChaCha](https://cr.yp.to/chacha.html) and read the papers. They're short. This generalizes to other algorithms; looking up the papers usually answers your questions quicker and better than reading most third-party summaries thereof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Luis Casillas said in his comment, the [spec of Salsa](https://cr.yp.to/snuffle/spec.pdf) is short and well explained. Namely, if you are interested in the expansion function, you can find a description with two examples (one with a 32-byte key, and one with a 16-byte key).

**Short answer:** when dealing with a 16-byte key, you only have to change a constant and append the key to itself.

More details bellow.

---

Salsa keystream generator, noted $Salsa20_k(n)$ for a key $k$ and a nonce $n$, is based on a hash function : $hSalsa20$ (called $Salsa20$ in the spec). This hash function works as follow : 
if $x$ is a 64-byte sequence, $hSalsa20(x)$ is a 64-byte sequence.

Now, let's see the role of the key and how it is managed. Whether you're using a 32-byte key or a 16-byte key, there is no real key expansion as you can find in Blowfish. Instead, the key $k$ is divided in two 16-bytes subkeys $k_0$ and $k_1$ (if $k$ is 16 bytes long, $k_1 = k_0$). Then, a 16-byte constant is added to the state, and that's where there is a difference : the value is not the same depending on the key size:

- for a 16-byte key, this constant is "expand 16-byte k"
- for a 32-byte key, this constant is "expand 32-byte k"

This constant is divided into 4 equal part, let's call them $\sigma_0,\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ and $\sigma_3$, 4-byte each.

The keystream is produced as follow :
$$Salsa20_k(n) = hSalsa20(\sigma_0\ ||\ k_0\ ||\ \sigma_1\ ||\ n\ ||\ \sigma_2\ ||\ k_1 || \sigma_3)$$
 where $||$ denotes the concatenation.

Notice that in both case, the argument of $hSalsa20$ is 64-byte, so 64-byte of keystream is produced. You only have to increment the nonce, and start over to generate more keystream.

Answer (score 1):

My answer follows from this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66744/83741) as suggested by @DannyNiu. The constant for $128$-bit ChaCha is "expand 16-byte k" in ASCII. So the four constant words are "expa", "nd 1", "6-by" and "te k" in ASCII. Converting them to HEX code we have

1. $c_0 = 0x61707865$
2. $c_1 = 0x312d646e$
3. $c_2 = 0x79622d36$
4. $c_3 = 0x6b2d6574$

Comment: Moderator note: this answer was merged from a different question that turned out to be a duplicate of the present question; hence the first sentence in this answer.