# Starting stream cypher, first block (Salsa20)

Tags: implementation, stream-cipher, salsa20

I'm implementing Salsa20 in Rust for fun.

I have the initial state (4x4 32-bit matrix) setup from the key, nonce, and stream position 0. I'm using the [Wikipedia Salsa20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20#Structure) article as reference, and I'm confused on how to encrypt the first block. QR is applied on the 4x4 matrix, but how do I "mix in" the input? Is there a better reference for this algorithm (or stream ciphers in general) I could use to understand the implementation?

Comment: Using the c code as reference might help :https://github.com/alexwebr/salsa20/blob/master/salsa20.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the [spec of Salsa20](https://cr.yp.to/snuffle/spec.pdf). It is quite short and easy to understand. You even have some examples for each component of the implementation.

---

For more details, you can take a look at [this post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66711/salsa20-chacha-with-128-bit-keys/66744#66744) which explains how to handle different key size (how to treat your initial block, and feed it to the Salsa hash function).